# Node.JS Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'MongoError' of module exports inside circular dependency

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-modules, circular-dependency

So this is my first try at an API, so I have literally no idea what I'm doing with Node.JS. I'm trying to make a MongoDB to hold my player data, but I keep getting the above error when I try to use the MongoDB driver.

This is the line that is causing me the issue:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
```

In my package.json for the project I am currently working on, these are the values:

```
"mongodb": {
      "version": "3.6.4",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb/-/mongodb-3.6.4.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-Y+Ki9iXE9jI+n9bVtbTOOdK0B95d6wVGSucwtBkvQ+HIvVdTCfpVRp01FDC24uhC/Q2WXQ8Lpq3/zwtB5Op9Qw==",
      "requires": {
        "bl": "^2.2.1",
        "bson": "^1.1.4",
        "denque": "^1.4.1",
        "require_optional": "^1.0.1",
        "safe-buffer": "^5.1.2",
        "saslprep": "^1.0.0"
      }
    },
    "mongoose": {
      "version": "5.11.15",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/mongoose/-/mongoose-5.11.15.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-8T4bT6eCGB7MqCm40oVhnhT/1AyAdwe+y1rYUhdl3ljsks3BpYz8whZgcMkIoh6VoCCjipOXRqZqdk1UByvlYA==",
      "requires": {
        "@types/mongodb": "^3.5.27",
        "bson": "^1.1.4",
        "kareem": "2.3.2",
        "mongodb": "3.6.3",
        "mongoose-legacy-pluralize": "1.0.2",
        "mpath": "0.8.3",
        "mquery": "3.2.3",
        "ms": "2.1.2",
        "regexp-clone": "1.0.0",
        "safe-buffer": "5.2.1",
        "sift": "7.0.1",
        "sliced": "1.0.1"
```

I've looked online for a solution and have already tried updating the Mongoose version, but that didn't solve it. Anything else that might be causing the issue?

Comment: @MontgomeryWatts Yes, for some reason essentially turning off and on again didn't occur to me xD. Thank you

Comment: How was this closed with that question as a similar question. Really perplexing. 
BTW Check this : https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/warning-accessing-non-existent-property-mongoerror-of-module-exports-inside-circular-dependency/15411/6, this should be fixed in next updates. The official team has reverted on the same.